# Print text between (and including) two delimiters on a line

Tags: sed, awk, cut

What's the best way to print the text between (and including) the first pattern ("SELECT" or "SSELECT") and a second pattern ("[") using a command-line took (e.g. cut, sed, awk)?

For example, given the following:

```
 54001744  KB035928      20  /dev/pts/8      SELECT PRINTER.LOCS WITH SHIP.TICK.BR = "15" [ INP @ 0x67E ]
 26083642  RV091101      25  /dev/pts/14     SSELECT PRODUCT BY STK.LN.SEQ [ MENU.SELECT @ 0x10C ]
 57082018  hajohug     0xACEBF1C1  SELECT ORDER.QUEUE WITH &INDEX&.STATUS = "S~S]" "H~S]" "A~S]" "M~S]" AND WITH &INDEX&.SBR "51 17~]" [ SOE.PH.ORDER.PRINT @ 0x384 ]
 50266386  hajohug     0xACEBF2F0  SSELECT UD.VIEWS WITH &INDEX& = "ORDERENTRY.ORDERENTRY~0" [ SOCKET.READ @ 0x168 ]
```

The result should be:

```
SELECT PRINTER.LOCS WITH SHIP.TICK.BR = "15"
SSELECT PRODUCT BY STK.LN.SEQ
SELECT ORDER.QUEUE WITH &INDEX&.STATUS = "S~S]" "H~S]" "A~S]" "M~S]" AND WITH &INDEX&.SBR "51 17~]"
SSELECT UD.VIEWS WITH &INDEX& = "ORDERENTRY.ORDERENTRY~0"
```

I've tried using cut, but I haven't been able to get things looking right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exactly match the final sequence in square brackets:

```
perl -alne 'm/S?SELECT.*?(?=\[ \S+ @ \S+ \]$)/ && print $&;' file
```

outputs

```
SELECT PRINTER.LOCS WITH SHIP.TICK.BR = "15" 
SSELECT PRODUCT BY STK.LN.SEQ 
SELECT ORDER.QUEUE WITH &INDEX&.STATUS = "S~S]" "H~S]" "A~S]" "M~S]" AND WITH &INDEX&.SBR "51 17~]" 
SSELECT UD.VIEWS WITH &INDEX& = "ORDERENTRY.ORDERENTRY~0"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly on the various *NIX variants I tested it. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, but did you checked also which strings are not matching?

Answer (score 3):

something like

```
sed 's@.*\(S*SELECT[^[]*\).*@\1@' foo
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You can use `perl`:

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if /(S?SELECT.*?)\[/' file
```

or using `grep`:

```
grep -Po 'S?SELECT.*?(?=\[)' file
```

Comment: `S?SELECT` or `S{1,2}ELECT` would be meet the requirements more exactly. You'll probably want `.*?` to be non-greedy before the `[`

Comment: Why do we need non-greedy?

Comment: In case there are more than 1 `[` on a line.

Comment: because there are `]` in the strings, the strings could also contain a `[`

Comment: Yeap, I only try on OP's input. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You can even use `grep` and `sed` as below.

```
grep -o 'SELECT.*$\|SSELECT.*$'  new.txt | sed 's/\[.*//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure POSIX `grep` solution:

```
grep -oE 'S?SELECT[^[]*' infile
```